# ionic3 Local notification and fcm it seems not working together

Tags: ios, angular, firebase, ionic3

I'm using ionic3 FCM plugin and local notification. Everything works fine on android, but on ios, when I'm in foreground the notification didn't appear:

```
"@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.18.0",
"@ionic-native/fcm": "^4.18.0",
"cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^2.4.0",
"cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.3",

this._localNotifications.schedule({
            id: 1,
            text: (data.text ? data.text : data.description),
            icon: "file://assets/icon/fcm_push_icon.png",
            smallIcon: "file://assets/icon/fcm_push_icon.png",
            color: "#424242",
            foreground: true,
            data: {url: data.url}
          })
```

Anyone know what's the problem ?